# Как тут работает сканер и как поправить задачу?

Tags: java

Задача:Описание

```
У нас есть несколько участников команды: программист, дизайнер, тестировщик. Нужно написать программу, которая поможет запланировать и рассчитать нагрузку и задать для каждого участника задачи на неделю (не больше 40 часов).

Функционал программы
Для каждого участника (программист, дизайнер, тестировщик) по очереди:

Ввести участника, для которого происходит планирование задач.
Запросить задачи в формате "Название и количество часов на задачу".
Посчитать количество уже введенных часов для участника. Если сумма превышает 40 часов, то прекратить ввод.
Перейти к вводу задач для другого участника.
Пример
Вас приветствует программа планировщик задач!
Давайте запланируем задачи на следующую неделю для команды.
Введите, для кого планируем?
Дизайнер <enter>
Введите название задачи:
Нарисовать макет сайта <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
20 <enter>
Введите название задачи:
Нарисовать логотип для Петра Ивановича <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
20 <enter>

Все 40 часов запланированы <enter>

Введите, для кого планируем?
Программист <enter>
Введите название задачи:
Продумать алгоритм работы менеджера задач <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
30 <enter>
Введите название задачи:
Написать менеджер задач <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
5 <enter>
Введите название задачи:
Выложить программу в маркет <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
10 <enter>

Задача слишком большая, нужно выбрать другую

Введите название задачи:
Помочь аналитику с документацией программы <enter>
Количество часов на задачу:
5 <enter>

Все 40 часов запланированы <enter>

Введите для кого планируем?
Тестировщик
...
Все 40 часов запланированы <enter>
<завершить работу программы>
Реализация
Создадим новый repl на сайте repl.it, как написано в инструкции к выполнению домашней работы, и зададим название homework1.2.2.

В файле Main.java написан следующий код:

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
Весь код выполнения задачи нужно писать вместо System.out.println("Hello world!");, эту строку нужно удалить.

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!"); //Код сюда
  }
Создадим следующие переменные в методе main:
int team = 3; //программист, дизайнер, тестировщик - количество участников команды
int maxHours = 40; //максимальное количество рабочих часов для каждого участника команды
Выведем следующие сообщения в консоль:
Вас приветствует программа планировщик задач!
Давайте запланируем задачи на следующую неделю для команды.
Создадим объект Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) для чтения данных из консоли, чтобы не создавать этот объект в цикле.

Создадим первый цикл, ограниченный количеством участников.

for (int i = 0; i < team; i++) {
    //TODO
}
Выведем в этом первом цикле сообщение:
Введите для кого планируем?
Прочитаем введенное значение scanner.nextLine() (можно никуда не сохранять название, в этой задаче оно нам больше не потребуется).

Создадим переменную int totalHours = 0. В нее будем сохранять количество всех часов уже введенных задач для данного участника.

Создадим второй вложенный цикл while, условие выхода из которого будет totalHours == 40 (если время задач участника больше 40 часов).

Во втором цикле по очереди выводим сообщения:

Введите название задачи:
Тест
Количество часов на задачу:
5
Проверяем, результат сложения введенного значения и totalHours меньше или равен 40?
Если да, то записываем в totalHours результат сложения.

Если нет, то выводим ошибку и предлагаем ввести другую задачу.

Продолжаем ввод, пока количество часов не достигнет 40 (totalHours == 40).

Выходим из вложенного цикла while и переходим к вводу задач для второго участника.

После ввода задач для всех участников команды завершаем работу программы.
```

Решение:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int team = 3;
            int maxHours = 40;

            System.out.println("Вас приветствует программа планировщик задач! Давайте запланируем задачи на следующую неделю для команды.");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            for (int i = 0; i < team; i++) {
                System.out.println("Введите для кого планируем?");

                scanner.nextLine();
                String worker = scanner.nextLine();

                int totalHours = 0;

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Введите название задачи:");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    String input = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Количество часов на задачу:");
                    int hours = scanner.nextInt();
                    totalHours = totalHours + hours;
                    if (totalHours > 40) {
                        System.out.println("Задача слишком большая, нужно выбрать другую");
                        totalHours = totalHours - hours;
                    }
                    if (totalHours == 40) {
                        System.out.println("Все 40 часов запланированы");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Собственно всю голову сломал, что бы поправить задачу в соответствии с комментарием: в решении этой задачи были использованы лишние сканеры, поэтому после ввода задачи необходимо дополнительно нажимать Enter.

Какие сканеры нужно убрать и почему именно так? Удаляя scanner.nextLine(); или String worker = scanner.nextLine(); программа не дает ввести данные при следующей итерации цикла.

Answer (score 0):

1) Если говорить о том, какие Сканеры надо убрать, то убирать следует оба `scanner.nextLine();` Это так, потому что инструкция `println()` автоматически переводит каретку ввода на следующую строку, и если оставить данные фрагменты кода, то клавишу Enter придется нажимать дважды. НО. Если убрать эти инструкции, на второй и третьей итерациях ввод имени участников пропускается. Поэтому я внес некоторые коррективы:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int team = 3;
        int maxHours = 40;

        System.out.println("Вас приветствует программа планировщик задач! Давайте запланируем задачи на следующую неделю для команды.");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < team; i++) {
            System.out.print("Введите для кого планируем?\n");

            while (true) {
                String worker = scanner.nextLine();
                if (worker.length() != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            int totalHours = 0;

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Введите название задачи:");

                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Количество часов на задачу:");
                int hours = scanner.nextInt();
                totalHours = totalHours + hours;
                if (totalHours > 40) {
                    System.out.println("Задача слишком большая, нужно выбрать другую");
                    totalHours = totalHours - hours;
                }
                if (totalHours == 40) {
                    System.out.println("Все 40 часов запланированы");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. При данном варианте кода пропускается ввод названия задачи, если их больше одной. Но аналогичная конструкция                                                                                                           
           while (true) {
                    String input = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (input.length() != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }      помогает решить вопрос.